# Display attribute 'Title' of element/s in other element on Focus or Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-experience

Show attribute 'Title' of elements (input type text, Select and Checkbox), on focus or click, in other element e.g.Label. 
Pls [see attached image link](http://r12i.imgup.net/Title-Labee296.png).

Thanks

Comment: That looks like an exercice...

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: I m not much into coding. Anyways I tried onBlur but it was only working for input type text.

Answer (score 0):

one of the possible solutions [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mhdq261/):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'input,select', function (e) {
    $('#current-control-label').text($(this).data().title);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'input,select', function (e) {
    $('#current-control-label').text(' ');
});
```

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-title="Name" /></td>
    <td>
        <select data-title="Gender">
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="M">Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" data-title="Active" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span id="current-control-label">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```